# Publishing work items to Azure Dev Ops from an existing Excel workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, team-foundation-server, azure-devops

I have an Excel sheet I use for creating stories and tasks into new release iterations, rather than creating them manually every time we create a new sprint. The sheet used to be connected to our on-premise TFS 2019 server, and I wish to use it with our on-premise Azure Dev Ops instance. When I open the Excel workbook it tells me the connection is stale, so I go to `Team` > `Configure` > `Server Connection` and connect to the new URL. This appears to work, in that Excel's status bar updates to say connected to ... but, the Team tab buttons are all still greyed out.

[image]

If I go into `Configure` > `Server Connection` again, the connection persists and is correct.

For reference, the work items templates are the same in the new instance.

How can I re-activate the other teams buttons, so that I can publish my stories and tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a new template, via `New List` on the Teams tab of the ribbon. The previous iteration of the Excel just wouldn't connect to the new Azure instance and update the connection dialogue in row A.